# Concurrent table update. EF Core Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, transactions

```
// here, sometimes getting old data or actual data but conflict updates, on multiple calls at the same time
var readyProduct = await _readyProductRepository.FindAsync(p => p.ModelId == readyProductCreate.ModelId);

if (readyProduct == null)
{
    readyProduct = _mapper.Map<ReadyProductCreate, ReadyProduct>(readyProductCreate);

    await _readyProductRepository.AddAsync(readyProduct);
}
else
{
    readyProduct.Count += readyProductCreate.Count;
    _readyProductRepository.Update(readyProduct);
}

var transaction = new ReadyProductTransaction
{
    ModelId = readyProductCreate.ModelId,
    Count = readyProductCreate.Count,
    Status = ReadyProductTransactionType.Import,
    Date = DateTime.Now,
};

await _transactionRepository.AddAsync(transaction);

await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
```

I covered the whole process in `Transaction` with isolation level `Serializable` but it made a `deadlock`.

Probably, creating a `trigger` after inserting the `ReadyProductTransaction` table to update the `ReadyProduct` table will be a solution but I was wondering if possible without the trigger.

DbContext - registered as Scoped

All repository classes including the UnitOfWork class - registered as Scoped

Application - .NET5.0

App running on - IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serializable` transactions are *more* likely, not *less* likely, to cause deadlocks, as they lock more and for longer.

This doesn't mean you shouldn't use them: better isolation is always going to be better for data integrity. You just need to use them correctly.

- Always make sure you lock tables in the same order, and try to ensure the same indexes get used in such locks.
- Use an Update lock. This prevents deadlocks by gating access to an exclusive lock, while still alowing pure read queries to run.
  In some DBMSs this is called `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. In SQL Server you add an `UPDLOCK` hint to a raw SQL query. For example:

```cs
var readyProduct = await _dbContext
    .FromSqlRaw<ReadyProduct>("SELECT * FROM dbo.ReadyProduct WITH (UPDLOCK)")
    .Where(p => p.ModelId == readyProductCreate.ModelId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Having said all that, consider not denormalizing your data in the first place. In other words, don't store the Count of child rows in the parent table. Instead, query the count of child rows when needed (possibly using an indexed view).

Comment: thanks for your time and the answer. One thing to clarify: so, I do not need the `ReadyProduct` table, and instead I should calculate based on the `ReadyProductTransaction` table?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal. This means you won't have Update Anomalies. If you have performance issues with such a solution, use an indexed view over the aggregation, as mentioned.

Comment: great, thanks!!